# How does a cleric gain new spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

Looking in the phb it is not clear how a cleric gains spells.  A wizard, for instance, can pick up 2 new spells per level increase and may find others that can be copied into a spell book.  The phb does indicate clearly how to determine the number of spells that a cleric can prepare, but that’s all I can see.